# Core data: Object ID changes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to fetch object by object ID in a simple core data implementation. Using this api

```
let targetObj = CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.privateQueueContext.object(with: self.objectID) as! MyObj
```

but it seems object id changes. Here is the console log

```
(lldb) po self.objectID
0xd000000000280000 <x-coredata://551DDB76-537D-41FA-B923-F772E5EE5D29/MyObj/p10>

(lldb) po CoreDataManager.sharedInstance.privateQueueContext.object(with: self.objectID).objectID
0xd000000000280006 <x-coredata://551DDB76-537D-41FA-B923-F772E5EE5D29/MyObj/p10>
```

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong. **Actually I'm book keeping these objectIds in an queue and need to dequeue the object based on these objectIds**.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: It's `<x-coredata://551DDB76-537D-41FA-B923-F772E5EE5D29/MyObj/p10>` in both cases. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @TomHarrington   I'm book keeping these objectIds in an array and need to check if array contains the object id or not

Answer (score 2):

The only difference you're seeing when you print each object ID is the address in memory where the object ID is stored.

So, if you take those two objects and compare them with `==` they will be different, because that is testing referential equality.

If you compare those two objects with `isEqual:`, it will return true, because `isEqual:` is testing whether the values they each represent are equal.

You can't reliably compare objects by reference, you need to use `isEqual:`.